# Text Appearing in Html is not present in DOM

Tags: python, selenium, dom, css-selectors

**Description:**

I am working on facebook automation and I face a problem and that is the text shown in the image: [image]

is appearing in `HTML` but when I use the selector to the element, I got a random text in a lot of spans as in the below html:

```
<span class="fsm fwn fcg"><span class="s_1k5vn5me3l"><a class="c_1k5vn5mh6v g_1k5vn5mh7c" href="#" role="button" id="u_ps_0_0_g"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s m_1k5vn5mh6z">S</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">y</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">j</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">b</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s m_1k5vn5mh6z">p</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">b</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">v</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">y</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s m_1k5vn5mh6z">o</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">k</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">j</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">v</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">y</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">w</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">w</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">y</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">k</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">S</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">j</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">b</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s m_1k5vn5mh6z">n</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">p</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">v</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">o</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">w</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">k</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s m_1k5vn5mh6z">s</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">n</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">w</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">w</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">j</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">y</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">j</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">j</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">s</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">v</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s m_1k5vn5mh6z">o</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">b</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">j</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">b</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">w</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">w</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">o</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">j</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">w</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">y</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">k</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s m_1k5vn5mh6z">r</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">w</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">r</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">b</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s m_1k5vn5mh6z">e</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">b</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">v</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">b</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">k</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">e</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s m_1k5vn5mh6z">d</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">v</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">d</span></span><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s f_1k5vn5mh7b s_1k5vn5mh79"><span class="l_1k5vn5mh6s v_1k5vn5mh6w">k</span></span>
                                                </span>
                                                </a></span></span>
```

I want to check either its sponsored post or not. But I am unable to check it out.

The `CSS-Selector` that I am trying  to get the **Sponsored** text is: `div._5pcp._5lel span`

**Secondly:**

I found an `XPath` to it which is returning me the text but when I want to collect that particular post's likes count and comments count it's returning me the count of the previous post or the once which is next to it but not for the post for the element which is in the current iteration of my `for` loop.

**Source Code is:**

**Note I just want to make check for 1st three posts:**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException, ElementNotVisibleException

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./../web_driver/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(0.5)

url_to_login = "https://www.facebook.com/"
driver.get(url_to_login)
time.sleep(3)

user_name = "username"
password = "password"

email_box = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
email_box.send_keys(user_name)

password_box = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
password_box.send_keys(password)
time.sleep(1)

login_button = driver.find_element_by_id("loginbutton")
login_button.click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").click()
time.sleep(2)


selector_for_all_posts = "div._4-u2.mbm._4mrt"
all_loaded_posts = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(selector_for_all_posts)[:3]

# posts_html = [BeautifulSoup(post.get_attribute("innerHTML"), 'lxml') for post in all_loaded_posts]

post_number = 0
for post in all_loaded_posts:
    print("Post#:", post_number)
    css_Selector = "div._5pcp._5lel span"
    check_sponsor_post_element = post.find_element_by_css_selector(css_Selector).text.strip()
    print("Post:", check_sponsor_post_element)
    if "Sponsored" == check_sponsor_post_element:
        post_anchor_text = post.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='fwn fcg']/span[@class='fwb fcg']/a")
        sponsor_title = post_anchor_text.text.strip()
        sponsor_link = post_anchor_text.get_attribute("href")
        total_likes = post.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='_81hb']").text
        total_comments = post.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='_3hg- _42ft']").text.replace("comments", "").strip()
        total_shares = post.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='_3rwx _42ft']").text.replace("shares", "").strip()
        print("Sponsor Title:", sponsor_title)
        print("Sponsor Link:", sponsor_link)
        print()
        print("Total Likes:", total_likes)
        print("Total Comments:", total_comments)
        print("Total Shares:", total_shares)
        postIndex = post_number
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a chance that there is no `text`. Maybe it's just an image with some text on it.

Regardless, if you are wanting to check if the element is there you don't need to get the text.

You can either:

1. Check if the element is present if it doesn't exist in both cases. `find_elements` is falsey if it finds 0 elements so you can put it directly in an `if` statement, or check the length of it and confirm that it's `> 0`
   `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(css_Selector)`

or

2. Check the values on the attributes of the element that are different depending on if it's sponsored or not.
   `if "value you expect" == post.find_element_by_css_selector(css_Selector).get_attribute("someAttributeNameOnTheElementLikeClassOrSomething"):`

It might be worth seeing if there is an element with the text and you're just looking in the wrong place as well... In Chrome devtools search for this Xpath `//*[contains(text(),'Sponsored')]` and see if one of the results is the element you want. Then update your `css_selector` accordingly.